# What's the difference between update stack and change set in AWS CloudFormation

Tags: aws-cloudformation

We can update the stack either by clicking on 'update' or 'selecting change set for the current stack', was curious to know what is the difference between these 2 options.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Short answer:**

- **Update stack** - for immediate deployment
- **Create Change set for current stack** - to prepare the changes and review them before deploying them.

**Detailed answer:**

**From AWS website -**
AWS CloudFormation provides two methods for updating stacks: direct update or creating and executing change sets.

When you directly update a stack, you submit changes and AWS CloudFormation immediately deploys them. Use direct updates when you want to quickly deploy your updates.

With change sets, you can preview the changes AWS CloudFormation will make to your stack, and then decide whether to apply those changes.
Change sets are JSON-formatted documents that summarize the changes AWS CloudFormation will make to a stack.

Use change sets when you want to ensure that AWS CloudFormation doesn't make unintentional changes or when you want to consider several options.

For example, you can use a change set to verify that AWS CloudFormation won't replace your stack's database instances during an update.*

Comment: But we can see changes, take in the update option too.

Comment: Technically, yes, you will see changes in update option also.
-It is more about the way of working when you have a big team, multiple stacks and reviewers.
-You can keep change sets ready ahead of time, keep them reviewed for the deployment day.
-You can get them reviewed in the update option also, but update option is for actual deployment, not for preparation for deployment after a week.
-You can review each template by update option and clicking few 'next' buttons and click 'cancel' after review. But better way would be keep change sets ready to be reviewed.
-It is more organized.